# TextBoxFor extension HTMLHelper

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

So I have this textbox on the page:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("EffectiveDate", Model.EffectiveDate.HasValue ? Model.EffectiveDate.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") : "", new { @class = "economicTextBox", propertyName = "EffectiveDate", onchange = "parseAndSetDt(this); ", dataType = "Date" })%>
```

It stores and displays a date using a date picker. Basically, depending on the users permission, I want this textbox to be disabled/enabled. This is fine, I can do this already, however, I want to make the textbox value = current date IF they don't have permission to change the value. I can use this HTML Extension to disable it w/ permissions:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxWithPermission(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
                                                  string name,
                                                  object value,
                                                  string[] permissions,
                                                  object htmlAttributes)
{
    foreach (string permission in permissions)
    {
        if (Chatham.Web.UI.Extranet.SessionManager.DisplayUser.IsInRole(permission))
        {
            // the user has the permission => render the textbox
            return htmlHelper.TextBox(name, value, htmlAttributes);
        }
    }

    // the user has no permission => render a readonly checkbox
    var mergedHtmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
    mergedHtmlAttributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
    return htmlHelper.TextBox(name, value, mergedHtmlAttributes);
}
```

But how do I fill it with the current date if it's disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, you just want to pass the current date as the value in the no permissions case, instead of the value passed into TextBoxWithPermission?

```
// the user has no permission => render a readonly checkbox
var mergedHtmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
mergedHtmlAttributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
return htmlHelper.TextBox(name, DateTime.Now, mergedHtmlAttributes);
```